# Как сделать скриншот окна?

Tags: c#, windows-10

Надо сделать скриншот отдельного окна на экране. Допустим калькулятора.
c#

Comment: какой ОС пользуетесь?

Comment: windows 10, какое это имеет значение?

Comment: от этого зависит ответ, в разных окружениях задача решается по-разному

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, я не смог найти решение совсем без P/Invoke. Вы должны найти нужный процесс (обычно он у вас и так есть, раз вы за ним следите), его окно (например, у класса [`Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) можно опросить `MainWindowHandle`), и у этого окна взять его координаты на экране. Для этого придётся вызывать WinAPI-функцию [`GetWindowRect`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowrect):

```
using System.Drawing;
```

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}
```

Скопировать кусок экрана можно при помощи функции [`Graphics.CopyFromScreen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.copyfromscreen(v=vs.110).aspx), которая доступна в WinForms. Если у вас не WinForms-приложение, придётся подключить `System.Drawing.dll`.

Получаем такой вот код:

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(тут имя процесса).FirstOrDefault();
// не забудьте поверку ошибок: вдруг у вас не нашлось ни одного процесса?
GetWindowRect(process.MainWindowHandle, out var rect);
using (var image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(rect.Left, rect.Top, 0, 0, image.Size);

    // тут у вас есть картинка, вы можете, например, сохранить её
    image.Save(imagePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
}
```

У меня получился вот такой скриншот окна Visual Studio:

[image: ну скриншот как скриншот]

Недостатки метода:

- окно должно быть на переднем плане, иначе вы получите перекрытые части
- могут быть проблемы с Aero-интерфейсом ([вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3072580/276994) решение, которое умеет бороться с этой проблемой, но я не проверял)

---

Обновление:

Я нашёл [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/911225/276994) решение, которое обходит первую проблему, то есть, умеет делать снимок окна, не находящегося на переднем плане. Для этого мы должны использовать ещё одну WinAPI-функцию `PrintWindow`. Вот улучшенный код:

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
```

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, out RECT lpRect);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool PrintWindow(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hdcBlt, int nFlags);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}
```

```
var process = Process.GetProcessesByName(тут имя процесса).FirstOrDefault();
// не забудьте поверку ошибок: вдруг у вас не нашлось ни одного процесса?
var hwnd = process.MainWindowHandle;
GetWindowRect(hwnd, out var rect);
using (var image = new Bitmap(rect.Right - rect.Left, rect.Bottom - rect.Top))
{
    using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image))
    {
        var hdcBitmap = graphics.GetHdc();
        PrintWindow(hwnd, hdcBitmap, 0);
        graphics.ReleaseHdc(hdcBitmap);
    }

    // тут у вас есть картинка, вы можете, например, сохранить её
    image.Save(imagePath, ImageFormat.Png);
}
```